# java/swing: clipboard paste

Tags: java, swing, clipboard

I have a DropTargetListener setup to allow me to drag + drop strings into some tables of my Swing application -- on a drop, I parse the string and insert data into the table.

I would like to do the same thing with a clipboard paste (Ctrl-V). **What literature is there to explain how to handle clipboard pastes?** I'm looking at [some stuff from Sun's website](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/dnd/listpaste.html) and it seems bizarre, like this should be simpler.

Answer (score 5):

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2793959/549510) by Bozhidar Batsov is the best solution I have seen around, simple and extensible. After adding his class file, this is how I implemented his class

```
txtTextField.addMouseListener(new ContextMenuMouseListener());
```

Adding additional actions should be pretty simple:

1. add a new `Action` class field,
2. Add the action to the `enum Actions`
3. Add an `AbstractAction` with the desired functions
4. Add the new action to the popup
5. Add the needed logic to the `mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)` method

And there you go. I added the detail here partly to make sure I understand it, and also to give those after me a clear understanding of what needs to be done. Don't forget to include the necessary `imports`!

Answer (score 3):

As shown in the [intro](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/dnd/intro.html) and the [`ListCutPaste`](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/examples/dnd/index.html#ListCutPaste) [demo](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorialJWS/uiswing/dnd/ex6/ListCutPaste.jnlp), the two are connected. The DnD gets you CCP automatically.

Answer (score 2):

I would instead suggest you to take a look at [java.awt.datatransfer.Clipboard](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/awt/datatransfer/Clipboard.html) class documentation. I think it will go along with your DnD operations.