# Why right click is not working on java application?

Tags: java, right-click

I had made one Java Swing based application.
On my application,if i click anywhere on the JFrame or anything, then my right click is not working?
i had not set anything like that..then why is not working?

Basically my key board was not working then i try to copy - paste data using mouse then, i came about to know that...my right click is not working on any area of my application...

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Your right click is working just fine - in Swing it's normal to not be getting the context menus you're used to in other apps. If you want to have a popup menu that opens up on right click with cut/copy/paste actions for example - you have to implement it yourself. I use something like this in my apps:

```
public class ContextMenuMouseListener extends MouseAdapter {
    private JPopupMenu popup = new JPopupMenu();

    private Action cutAction;
    private Action copyAction;
    private Action pasteAction;
    private Action undoAction;
    private Action selectAllAction;

    private JTextComponent textComponent;
    private String savedString = "";
    private Actions lastActionSelected;

    private enum Actions { UNDO, CUT, COPY, PASTE, SELECT_ALL };

    public ContextMenuMouseListener() {
        undoAction = new AbstractAction("Undo") {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                    textComponent.setText("");
                    textComponent.replaceSelection(savedString);

                    lastActionSelected = Actions.UNDO;
            }
        };

        popup.add(undoAction);
        popup.addSeparator();

        cutAction = new AbstractAction("Cut") {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                lastActionSelected = Actions.CUT;
                savedString = textComponent.getText();
                textComponent.cut();
            }
        };

        popup.add(cutAction);

        copyAction = new AbstractAction("Copy") {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                lastActionSelected = Actions.COPY;
                textComponent.copy();
            }
        };

        popup.add(copyAction);

        pasteAction = new AbstractAction("Paste") {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                lastActionSelected = Actions.PASTE;
                savedString = textComponent.getText();
                textComponent.paste();
            }
        };

        popup.add(pasteAction);
        popup.addSeparator();

        selectAllAction = new AbstractAction("Select All") {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                lastActionSelected = Actions.SELECT_ALL;
                textComponent.selectAll();
            }
        };

        popup.add(selectAllAction);
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        if (e.getModifiers() == InputEvent.BUTTON3_MASK) {
            if (!(e.getSource() instanceof JTextComponent)) {
                return;
            }

            textComponent = (JTextComponent) e.getSource();
            textComponent.requestFocus();

            boolean enabled = textComponent.isEnabled();
            boolean editable = textComponent.isEditable();
            boolean nonempty = !(textComponent.getText() == null || textComponent.getText().equals(""));
            boolean marked = textComponent.getSelectedText() != null;

            boolean pasteAvailable = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().getContents(null).isDataFlavorSupported(DataFlavor.stringFlavor);

            undoAction.setEnabled(enabled && editable && (lastActionSelected == Actions.CUT || lastActionSelected == Actions.PASTE));
            cutAction.setEnabled(enabled && editable && marked);
            copyAction.setEnabled(enabled && marked);
            pasteAction.setEnabled(enabled && editable && pasteAvailable);
            selectAllAction.setEnabled(enabled && nonempty);

            int nx = e.getX();

            if (nx > 500) {
                nx = nx - popup.getSize().width;
            }

            popup.show(e.getComponent(), nx, e.getY() - popup.getSize().height);
        }
    }
}
```

In the end you should attach this listener to any text components that you want to have a context menu on right click.

Comment: Fantastic!  Just what I was looking for.  For any newbies out there, add this as a new file to your project, then, on your txt component, say something like this: 
  txtDescription.addMouseListener(new ContextMenuMouseListener());

Comment: Perfect, thanks for sharing this. I have used your class for an answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11915456/549510

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean you don't get a context menu? In Swing applications you have to add a context-menu yourself.
See [this article](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html) for further information.

Answer (score 1):

```
class Popup extends JPopupMenu
{
    final static long serialVersionUID = 0;

    Clipboard clipboard;

    UndoManager undoManager;

    JMenuItem jmenuItem_undo;
    JMenuItem jmenuItem_cut;
    JMenuItem jmenuItem_copy;
    JMenuItem jmenuItem_paste;
    JMenuItem jmenuItem_delete;
    JMenuItem jmenuItem_selectAll;

    JTextComponent jtextComponent;

    public Popup()
    {
        undoManager = new UndoManager();

        clipboard = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();

        jmenuItem_undo = new JMenuItem("undo");
        jmenuItem_undo.setEnabled(false);
        jmenuItem_undo.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
            {
                undoManager.undo();
            }
        });

        this.add(jmenuItem_undo);

        this.add(new JSeparator());

        jmenuItem_cut = new JMenuItem("cut");
        jmenuItem_cut.setEnabled(false);
        jmenuItem_cut.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
            {
                jtextComponent.cut();
            }
        });

        this.add(jmenuItem_cut);

        jmenuItem_copy = new JMenuItem("copy");
        jmenuItem_copy.setEnabled(false);
        jmenuItem_copy.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
            {
                jtextComponent.copy();
            }
        });

        this.add(jmenuItem_copy);

        jmenuItem_paste = new JMenuItem("paste");
        jmenuItem_paste.setEnabled(false);
        jmenuItem_paste.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
            {
                jtextComponent.paste();
            }
        });

        this.add(jmenuItem_paste);

        jmenuItem_delete = new JMenuItem("delete");
        jmenuItem_delete.setEnabled(false);
        jmenuItem_delete.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
            {
                jtextComponent.replaceSelection("");
            }
        });

        this.add(jmenuItem_delete);

        this.add(new JSeparator());

        jmenuItem_selectAll = new JMenuItem("select all");
        jmenuItem_selectAll.setEnabled(false);
        jmenuItem_selectAll.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
            {
                jtextComponent.selectAll();
            }
        });

        this.add(jmenuItem_selectAll);
    }

    public void add(JTextComponent jtextComponent)
    {
        jtextComponent.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter()
        {
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent event)
            {
                if (event.getButton() == 3)
                {
                    processClick(event);
                }
            }
        });

        jtextComponent.getDocument().addUndoableEditListener(new UndoableEditListener()
        {
            public void undoableEditHappened(UndoableEditEvent event)
            {
                undoManager.addEdit(event.getEdit());
            }
        });
    }

    private void processClick(MouseEvent event)
    {
        jtextComponent = (JTextComponent)event.getSource();

        boolean enableUndo = undoManager.canUndo();
        boolean enableCut = false;
        boolean enableCopy = false;
        boolean enablePaste = false;
        boolean enableDelete = false;
        boolean enableSelectAll = false;

        String selectedText = jtextComponent.getSelectedText();
        String text = jtextComponent.getText();

        if (text != null)
        {
            if (text.length() > 0)
            {
                enableSelectAll = true;
            }
        }

        if (selectedText != null)
        {
            if (selectedText.length() > 0)
            {
                enableCut = true;
                enableCopy = true;
                enableDelete = true;
            }
        }

        try
        {
            if (clipboard.getData(DataFlavor.stringFlavor) != null)
            {
                enablePaste = true;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            System.out.println(exception);
        }

        jmenuItem_undo.setEnabled(enableUndo);
        jmenuItem_cut.setEnabled(enableCut);
        jmenuItem_copy.setEnabled(enableCopy);
        jmenuItem_paste.setEnabled(enablePaste);
        jmenuItem_delete.setEnabled(enableDelete);
        jmenuItem_selectAll.setEnabled(enableSelectAll);

        this.show(jtextComponent,event.getX(),event.getY());
    }
}
```

and to implement it,

```
Popup popup = new Popup();

JTextArea jtextArea;
JTextField jtextField;

popup.add(jtextArea);
popup.add(jtextField);
```