# Providing copy/paste menu to a large number of JTextFields

Tags: java, swing, clipboard, jtextfield

A program of mine has a large number of JTextField elements. I'd like to provide a way to copy text from the text fields to the system clipboard. I found multiple methods of how to do this online (such as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9021269/right-click-to-copy-and-paste-in-java)), but they don't perform well with multiple fields, short of spamming duplicate code for each element, something that's hardly desirable for the large number of text fields.

So, is there a simple way to add the ability to copy and paste from multiple text fields in a Java Swing application?

Comment: Copy from multiple text fields meaning ?

Comment: @Rakesh meaning the ability to copy and paste from a single text field, but apply the ability to copy and paste to a large number of text fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I always make the same answer, but you can use `Key Bindings` 
[How to use KeyBindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html)

Suppose your textfields lives in the same container..

```
AbstractAction copyAction = new AbstractAction() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            for(Component c : container.getComponents()){
                     if(c instanceof JTextField){
                       //add copy paste action
                     }
            }
    }};
 String key = "YOUR KEY COMBINATION HERE";
 KeyStroke keyStroke = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(key);
 component.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
 component.getActionMap().put(key, copyAction);
```

Answer (score 1):

Create your own JTextfield that will implement the functionality.